# exported e4 RCP application Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an eclipse plug-in developed as an E4Application and runs fine when launched via the 'product' file within eclipse.

However, when exported via the Product Export Wizard, generated exec launches fine (no exceptions thrown, Parts and icons are displayed) but the Parts are not initialised. Parts are designed to be initialised by the @PostConstruct annotated init functions and those methods do expect parameters such as Composite, IEclipseContext, EMenuService etc to be injected.

So, who would inject these objects on a stand alone application? Especially what about eclipse specific objects such as IEclipseContext.

If anything is not clear, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

O.

Comment: DI should be working in the exported product, and it works for me (V 4.2.2). What exactly are you injecting? If you are injecting a service of your own which is not initialized for some reason, and if the parameter is not marked as @Optional then the method will not be called, because of the missing parameter.

Comment: Also, how does your MANIFEST.MF refer to the annotations?  Do you use Import-Package?

Comment: I have same problem. Commands from e4xmi fragments not working after export. As for dependencies, I always using required plugins import instead of imported packages.